# Compare two dataframes columns and find string similiraties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im in a project using python where i have two dataframes

| Product Name | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Car with batteries | 2 |
| Headphones Sony | 3 |

| Product Name | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Car batteries | 2 |
| Headphones Sony | 3 |

What i have to do is compare this dataframes and put a column that said 'Matches'
But like you see it have to compare Car with batteries and Car batteries and put matches because they are the same product.
It is possible?.

Comment: I think you are looking for fuzzy matching. There are a couple of ways to achieve this and you will need to try them out to see what works best. First would be the fuzzy-pandas https://pypi.org/project/fuzzy-pandas/ library, or you could try to use the fuzzywuzzy library, see e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-do-fuzzy-matching-on-pandas-dataframe-column-using-python/.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first dataframe is `df1` and the second one is `df2`, you can:

- Create a new column in the dataframe of your choice (either `df1`, `df2` or even a new one)
- Call this new column `"Matched"`
- Populate the new column values with the results from the condition: populate with `True` if the condition is true, otherwise populate with `False`:

```py
    df1["Matches"] = df1["Cost"] ==  df1["Cost"]
```

This will create a new column of True/False values based on whether the battery costs of the same rows in the 2 dataframes match or not (assumes that `df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) to find the similarity of the values. Using for example `fuzz.ratio(str1, str2)` will return you an indicator how similar the strings are. There are other methods as well. You would have to find out yourself what suits best for your use case.

---

The example below uses `fuzz.ratio(str1, str2)` and considers a ratio of 80 to be equals:

```py
# pip install fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein
# or: conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy python-levenshtein

import io
import pandas as pd

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Product Name, Cost
Car with batteries, 2
Headphones Sony, 3
"""))

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Product Name, Cost
Car batteries, 2
Headphones Sony, 3
"""))
```

```py
COLUMN_NAME = "Product Name"
ACCEPTED_RATIO = 80

def match(right, left):
    return fuzz.ratio(right, left) > ACCEPTED_RATIO

rsuffix = "_r"
compared = df1.join(df2, rsuffix=rsuffix)
compared["Matches"] = compared.apply(
    lambda x: match(x[COLUMN_NAME], x[f"{COLUMN_NAME}{rsuffix}"]),
    axis=1,
)
compared = compared.drop(
    [c for c in compared.columns if c.endswith(rsuffix)],
    axis=1
)
```

And the output of `print(compared)` would be:

```
          Product Name  Cost    Matches
0   Car with batteries     2       True
1      Headphones Sony     3       True
```